# Print a binary tree path with leaf value in a Stack

Tags: java, algorithm

To print a binary tree path with a leaf node value. When it backtracks, it should remove the '3' from the stack. How to modify the code to achieve? I can't find a place to pop the value from the stack.

```
// should print out "5 8 10", but it prints "5 3 8 10"
printPathWithStack(root, 5); 

      10
     /   \
    8      2
   /  \    /
 3    5  4

void printPathWithStack(Node root, int key)
{
    Stack<Node> path = new Stack<Node>();
    printPathWithStackHelper(root, key, path);
}

void printPathWithStackHelper(Node root, int key, Stack<Node> path)
{
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }

    path.push(root);

    if (root.data == key && root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        while (!path.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(path.pop().data + " ");
        }
    } else if (root.left == null && root.right == null){
            path.pop();
     } 

    printPathWithStackHelper(root.left, key, path);
    printPathWithStackHelper(root.right, key, path);
}
```

Comment: You're mixing recursive and non-recursive concepts here.  You should either be using your stack object and not making any recursive calls, or you should not be using a stack object and relying on the program execution stack.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit strange to use the stack this way.

But for what it's worth, when backtracking you should simply discard all items where `item.left` or `item.right` is not equal the last retrieved item. This will give you the path to the root.

Comment: The problem is where to discard those items?

Answer (score 0):

You can defer pushing into Stack until making recursive calls to left and right child.

```
 if (root.data == key && root.left == null && root.right == null) 
 {
    path.push(root);
    while (!path.isEmpty()) 
    {
        System.out.print(path.pop().data + " ");
    }
    return;
 } 
 else if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
 {
        return;
 } 
 path.push(root);
 printPathWithStackHelper(root.left, key, path);
 printPathWithStackHelper(root.right, key, path);
```

Hope it addresses your problem!

P.S. Not tested the code fragment for general cases, hope you will do the required :)